# how to create two class at a js page in node js?

Tags: node.js, oop, ecmascript-6

```
class tasit {
 constructor(cins) {
  this.cins = cins;
 }  
}
class araba extends tasit {
 constructor(cins, renk, hiz) {
  super(cins);
  this.renk = renk;
  this.hiz = hiz;
 }
}
module.exports = {tasit, araba};
```

I want to create 2 classes in a .js file and I want to export them. How do I export or do I can export classes?

```
module.exports = {tasit, araba};
```

here is error message.

```
ReferenceError: araba is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your export is just fine. This is one way to import your classes:

```
// Assuming you've created your classes in myclasses.js
const {Araba, Tasit} = require('./myclasses.js')

myAraba = new Araba(1, 'a', true)
myTasit = new Tasit(10)


console.log(myAraba.hiz, myAraba.renk, myAraba.cins)
console.log(myTasit.cins)
```

outputs

> true 'a' 1
>   10

Only note that I capitalized your class names.

Comment: @salihgungor My pleasure.